# Stripe - yearly "reversed proration" subscription

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment, subscription

I am using Stripe to collect payments from Stripe. I'm currently developing yearly subscriptions. As per specifics, we would like to have same yearly/per-seat model as Slack.

This means that you pay yearly price for seats at the time of the upgrade to yearly plan. But then if you add a user to the plan, you are prorated towards "next bill" and billed immediately.

For instance, you upgrade to yearly plan on 1.1.2021 for 100$ and after half year you add one more user so you get billed 50$ immediately. After 3/4 year you get billed 25$.

Stripe currently allows proration based on usage, not towards the next billing cycle. Can someone help me how to correctly handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by [updating the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) with new products/quantities depending on how you currently handle seats and using the default behavior of [`proration_behavior`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior) . The [API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) for updating subscriptions explains the way this proration works (which I believe is what you're looking for):

> By default, we prorate subscription changes. For example, if a customer signs up on May 1 for a €100 price, she'll be billed €100 immediately. If on May 15 she switches to a €200 price, then on June 1 she'll be billed €250 (€200 for a renewal of her subscription, plus a €50 prorating adjustment for half of the previous month's €100 difference). Similarly, a downgrade will generate a credit to be applied to the next invoice. We also prorate when you make quantity changes.

Some things of note:

- If you update the billing cycle, the user is charged the proration amount immediately instead of at the end of the cycle [(source)](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#prorations)
- You can update the subscription whenever you want as long as it is before the next invoice is finalized. Read about Invoices created from Subscriptions [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#invoice-lifecycle).